# Complex analysis: limit point at infinity

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $S\subset\overline{\mathbb C}$.
Are the following two statements equivalent?

> $\infty$ is a limit point of $S$.

and

> For every $M>0$, there exists $l\in S$ such that $|l|>M$.

Intuitively this is correct, since we have points arbitrarily far away from the origin, so we have points arbitrarily close to $\infty$.

However, I don’t fully trust my intuition. Moreover, even if my intuition is correct, I cannot rigorously prove that the statements are equivalent.

Is my intuition correct? If yes, how can I rigorously prove the equivalence of these two statements?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A good place to start would be by writing down the relevant definition of a *limit point*.  What does it mean for a point $s\in\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ to be a limit point of $S$?  Depending on how much topology you know and/or how rigourous you are trying to be, there are a couple of ways of verifying your intuition.  But, again, they all start with a definition.

Comment: Reading up on the Riemann Sphere may help build your intuition.

Comment: @XanderHenderson For the set $S=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots\}$, define $S_\theta=\{2\cot^{-1}s_k\}$ for $k\ge1$. If for every $M>0$, there exist $k\in S$ s.t. $|k|>M$, then there exist $j\in S_\theta$ s.t. $j\le 2\cot^{-1}M$. So elements in $S_\theta$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$. And then I cannot continue.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Please kindly read my previous comment. I can show that there are elements in $S_\theta$ that is arbitrarily close to $0$, but I encounter difficulties to link that with the definition of limit point.

Comment: What is the definition of "limit point" in your text?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry it should be $S_\theta=\{2\cot^{-1}|s_k|\}$.

Comment: @xbh Just the usual definition.

Comment: @Szeto Well, the so called "usual" definition would vary. For your question, the 2nd statement seems a definition of limit points **to me**, but maybe not to you [per your text]

Comment: Again, a good place to start is by *writing down* the relevant definition of a limit point.  You should edit your question to include that.  There are several different (equivalent) definitions–no one is going to be able to answer your question if you don't tell us where to start.  Indeed, as xbh notes, I would regard your second statement as the "usual" definition.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by $\infty$ being a limit point of $S$ you mean that every neighbourhood of $\infty$ contains a point in $S$ that is not $\infty$. Recall that the topology on the Riemann sphere is defined so that every open neighbourhood of $\infty$ is of the form $\{\infty\} \cup (\mathbb{C} \backslash C)$ for some closed and compact set $C \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

Now, assume that $\infty$ is a limit point of $S$. Let $M > 0$ and consider the neighbourhood $\{\infty\} \cup (\mathbb{C}\backslash \overline{B_M(0)})$ where $\overline{B_M(0)}$ is the closed ball of radius $M$ around $0$. By assumption, there is some $l \in S$ with $l \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \overline{B_M(0)}$ and so $|l|>M$.

For the other direction, assume that $\infty$ is not a limit point of $S$. Then there is some open neighbourhood $\{\infty\} \cup (\mathbb{C} \backslash C)$ that contains no elements of $S$. This implies $S \subseteq C$. Since $C$ is compact, it is bounded by the Heine-Borel theorem and we are done.

Comment: Does the ‘closed ball of radius M’ mean a circle with radius M on complex plane mapped onto the Riemann sphere?

Comment: It means the set of complex numbers with norm less than or equal to $M$.